# Best practice for iterating and inserting into sqlute db from JSON object array

Tags: json, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am sending back compressed data from a web service call which returns a json array filled with Objects that have an array with key/value pairs. Some of these may or may not return as empty objects, which is fine. Just means there were no updates.

My json object after decompressed returns in this format:

```
{
 "Warehouse":[[]],
 "Managers":[{"ID":"12404","EmployeeID":"4776","Name":"Sammy Silver"},   {"ID":"12405","EmployeeID":"4778","Name":"Tom Castro"} ],
 "T1":[{"ID":"60458","EmployeeID":"25902","Name":"Angela Li"}...,...,]
"DeletedWarehouse" : [{"ID":"70141","EmployeeID":"12345","Name":"Victor Bajas"}...,...]
```

My code looks like this:

```
 var jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

My Root:

```
public class Root
    {
        public List< Warehouse > Warehouse { get; set; }
        public List< Management > Managers { get; set; }
        public List< Top > T1 { get; set; }
        public List< Warehouse > DeletedWarehouse { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to update the rows that are considered updated like the warehouse, managers and T1. Warehouse was empty .. so nothing should happen there, but the rest I am trying to iterate through them to run a query to my local database. However I son't think I am doing this correctly. I think I am repeating myself too much and I don't want to do that, but I can't think of a different way.

```
if(jsonList.Warehouse.Count > 0)
     {
         //loop and  insert or replace here..
     }
     if(jsonList.Managers.Count > 0)
     {
      //loop and  insert or update
     }
     if(jsonList.T1.Count > 0)
     {
      //loop and  insert or update
     }
     if(jsonList.DeletedWarehouse.Count > 0)
     {
       //loop and delete from table
     }
```

I am using a dbmaanger class where I store all my sqlite interaction, so I am going to make a function where I either insert or replace or delete the row all together.
But before I do that I wanted to see of my logic above was okay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the rows that are considered updated like the warehouse, managers and T1. Warehouse was empty .. so nothing should happen there, but the rest I am trying to iterate through them to run a query to my local database.

You can foreach jsonList and find the current data in the database by id, if yes, just update, if not, insert.

```
public  class SQLiteHelper
{
    SQLiteAsyncConnection db;
    public SQLiteHelper(string dbPath)
    {
        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        //db.CreateTableAsync<Person>().Wait();
        db.CreateTableAsync<Managers>().Wait();
    }

    //Insert and Update new record  
    public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(Managers person)
    {
        if (person.ID != null)
        {
            return db.UpdateAsync(person);
        }
        else
        {
            return db.InsertAsync(person);
        }
    }

   
}

 SQLiteHelper db;
    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         db = new SQLiteHelper(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "XamarinSQLite.db3"));
    }

    private void btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (jsonList.Managers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(Managers item in jsonList.Managers)
            {
                db.SaveItemAsync(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you suggest I should loop through the items like I showed above? Like in your case iterate through jsonlist.Managers, jsonlist.Warehouse, jsonlist.T1 and use SavveItemAync but for each category?

Comment: What about having my JSON return sqllite queries so they can execute when ran. Like "Insert or update...","Insert or update...","Insert or update...","Insert or update..." and then "Delete from.." for the records I need to delete? Just a thought and something I came across a while ago but I can't find anything like that now.

Comment: @Jay2020 What you mean? Do you want to parse Json and insert data or update data in sqlite? I am not sure what you want to do now.

Comment: well both. There is a local database inside the app currently. However in order for the user to get new data/ updated data I make a web service call. Which is this one up here ^^. I am returning JSON data and I am parsing it. However my iteration through that data I think is incorrect because I am essentially iterating through each sub list and then iterating through that sublist to make the proper insert/delete/updates. Not sure if I am explaining myself correctly. I just believe there is too much repetition. I thought doing what I suggested in the prev comment would be different but idk

Comment: @jay2020 You think you have some problem about iteration, can you provide one simple sample about your problem?